# setInterval - How to fire only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

Hello I have this snippet of code that will fire some even after time that I choose.

The problem is that if, for example I put 3 seconds it will fire every 3 seconds, what I need is it to fire only once after 3 seconds.

```
function playSound(timeLeft){
   var sendDataTimeout = function(){
      alert('OK');
   }
   var intervalReference = 0;
   clearInterval(intervalReference);
   intervalReference = setInterval(sendDataTimeout, timeLeft);
}
```

Comment: alternatively, make the `intervalReference` global (move it outside of the `playSound` function and then clear it inside `senDataTimeout` - but I would opt in for `setTimeout`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `setTimeout` instead, it works almost the same but will only fire once. You have `clearTimeout` and `setTimeout` so its very similar to setInterval

```
function playSound(timeLeft){
   var sendDataTimeout = function(){
      alert('OK');
   }
   setTimeout(sendDataTimeout, timeLeft);
}
```

You don't have to use clearTimeout anymore. But FYI it exist and works the same as clearInterval.

Comment: This is really helpful when doing React `setState` recurring increments based on intervals/timing, especially within `useEffect`.  If you provide the variable whose state is to change as a dependency to `useEffect` and then have a `setTimeout`, it'll be guaranteed to run once and then be rebuilt into a new timeout after it changes the state.

Answer (score 13):

You don't need `setInterval`, you need `setTimeout`.

As the name says, `setInterval` fires regularly, while `setTimeout` fires only once. The usage is the same though.